# Submit button from partial rendered via ajax doesn't redirect, using rails 3.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, redirect, partial

I'm having this issue where I can render a partial view by clicking on a radio button but when I click the submit button inside the partial to create a new user the user is created successfully but the form doesn't redirect to the user page, it just creates a new user in the background so you only see the new user after you refresh the page.  Does anyone know how to get it so when I click the submit button it will redirect to a page?

index.html.erb

```
Listing users
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
<%= form_tag({:action => 'preview'}, :remote => true, :'data-update-target' => 'update-container') do %>
<%= label_tag :gender, 'male' %>
<%= radio_button_tag :gender, 'male', false, :class => 'submit' %><br/>
<%= label_tag :gender, 'female' %>
<%= radio_button_tag :gender, 'female', false, :class => 'submit' %>
<%=# submit_tag 'Submit', :disable_with => 'Please wait...', :class => 'submit' 
%>
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def index
  @users = User.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @users }
  end
end
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @user }
  end
end
def new
  @user = User.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @user }
  end
end
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
# POST /users
# POST /users.json
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
# PUT /users/1
# PUT /users/1.json
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
# DELETE /users/1
# DELETE /users/1.json
def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to users_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
def preview
  if params[:gender] == "male"
    @userd = User.new
    render :partial => 'preview', :object => @userd
  elsif params[:gender] == "female"
    @userd = User.new
    render :partial => 'preview', :object => @userd
  end
end
end
```

_preview.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@userd, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and my application.js

```
$(function() {
/* Convenience for forms or links that return HTML from a remote ajax call.
The returned markup will be inserted into the element id specified.
*/
  $('form[data-update-target]').live('ajax:success', function(evt, data) {
    var target = $(this).data('update-target');
    $('#' + target).html(data);
  });
  $('input.submit').click(function(){ $(this).parent().submit(); return true; });
  });
```